Can a company charge a fee for providing source code of open-source SW used in their product?
The User Manual of our dishwasher contains an article titled Information on free and open-source software. Within this article, the manufacturer states that the source code will be provided upon a request sent either by e-mail or by mail. The article ends with this statement:

You will be charged for your request costs.

Is it legal to charge fees for source code of open-source software utilized in a manufacturer's product when requested by e-mail? Either way, on what grounds specifically?
The company and I reside in EU.

Can you clarify what that Company is charging for? 'You will be charged for your request costs' isn't clear in English.
Still, would it be unreasonable for your Company to charge for the trouble it clearly would take to provide you with the code?
Would it be OK to charge postage and packing on a printed copy of the code?
Pushing a button to send an e-version is clearly cheaper and if Company is paying anyone to to do it,  pushing that button would not cost nothing.

It depends on the licensing terms between the dishwasher manufacturer and the software vendor(s). There is nothing in the Free Software Definition nor the Open Source Definition which requires making the source code available free of charge.
In fact, the Open Source Definition, section 2. Source Code explicitly says [bold italic emphasis mine]:

Where some form of a product is not distributed with source code, there must be a well-publicized means of obtaining the source code for no more than a reasonable reproduction cost, preferably downloading via the Internet without charge.

So, while the OSD restricts the amount that can be charged, and expresses a preference for making the source code available free of charge, it does explicitly acknowledge and allow charging to recover the reproduction cost.
Some Free and Open Source Licenses do not require the dishwasher manufacturer to provide the source code at all, for example, the MIT X11 License, MIT No Attribution License, ISC License, and the 1-Clause, 2-Clause, and 3-Clause BSD Licenses.
Only so-called copyleft licenses require making the source code available. The most well-known copyleft licenses are the GNU General Public License and the GNU Affero General Public License, but as covered in JustAnotherCoder's answer, those explicitly allow charging for the source code, too.

This will probably depend on the exact licence(s) the software falls under, but as an example, GPL2 and GPL3 both permit a fee to obtain the source code, provided that this only covers the actual cost of distributing the source to you.
GPL2, section 3b:

Accompany [the software] with a written offer, valid for at least three years, to give any third party, for a charge no more than your cost of physically performing source distribution, a complete machine-readable copy of the corresponding source code to be distributed under the terms of Sections 1 and 2 above on a medium customarily used for software interchange

GPL3, section 6b:

Convey the object code in, or embodied in, a physical product (including a physical distribution medium), accompanied by a written offer, valid for at least three years and valid for as long as you offer spare parts or customer support for that product model, to give anyone who possesses the object code either (1) a copy of the Corresponding Source for all the software in the product that is covered by this License, on a durable physical medium customarily used for software interchange, for a price no more than your reasonable cost of physically performing this conveying of source or (2) access to copy the Corresponding Source from a network server at no charge.


And these days that condition would usually be moot. It was written when a typical way to "convey" was by sending a floppy disk. With online downloads the norm now, there's no "physically performing" involved and the marginal cost is 0.

But apparently the washing machine manufacturer doesn't offer downloads.

@Barmar It's not moot, the terms of GPLv2 requires that the source code is made available via physical media if it does not accompany the binary distribution. Nothing prohibits downloads, but it does not fulfill the condition of the license. An Internet option is added in GPLv3, but it does not affect software under GPLv2.

@user71659 I was about to wonder who still has the ability to write floppies, but these days it would probably be a thumb drive.

@Barmar someone still has to actually do it. If the company is staffed by robots, (physical or electronic) they still incur a cost for their maintenance and upkeep.

I know, I'm not contradicting you. And they can also charge for the cost of the drive.
